# Grouping xml nodes on a single line using Xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

How I can group my elements on a single line?
I want all my nodes to be in a single line and to be sorted after name's child.
I don't have any idea how can I do this!

**> XML input:**

```
`<parent>
<Node  ID="a">
      <Name>first</Name>
      <ID>0x1</ID>
      <info>the first nod</info>
      <numb>8</numb>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <child>
      <Name>ch1</Name>
      <ID>0x11</ID>
      <info>the first child</info>
      <numb>7</numb>
      <Comment></Comment>
      </child>
      ...
      <other>
        <Name>attr</Name>
        <Value>No</Value>
        <DefaultUsed>No</DefaultUsed>
      </other>
      <other>
        <Name>attr</Name>
        <Value>No</Value>
        <DefaultUsed>No</DefaultUsed>
      </other>
</Node>
<Node  ID="b">
      <Name>second</Name>
      <ID>0x2</ID>
      <info>the second nod</info>
      <numb>9</numb>
      <Comment></Comment>
      <child>
      <Name>ch2</Name>
      <ID>0x22</ID>
      <info>the second child</info>
      <numb>7</numb>
      <Comment></Comment>
      </child>
      ....
      <other>
        <Name>attr1</Name>
        <Value>No</Value>
        <DefaultUsed>No</DefaultUsed>
      </other>
      <other>
        <Name>attr1</Name>
        <Value>No</Value>
        <DefaultUsed>No</DefaultUsed>
      </other>
</Node>
</parent>
`
```

**XML output**

```
`<Node ; "Name= first","ID=0x1","info=the first nod","numb=8">
<child ;"Name= ch1","ID=0x11","info=the first child","numb=7">
....
<Node ; "Name= second","ID=0x2","info=the second nod","numb=9">
<child ;"Name= ch2","ID=0x22","info=the second child","numb=7">
`
```

Can someone help me? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that you show is not well-formed XML. You can get an output  of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Node Name="first" ID="0x1" info="the first nod" numb="8">
      <child Name="ch1" ID="0x11" info="the first child" numb="7"/>
   </Node>
   <Node Name="second" ID="0x2" info="the second nod" numb="9">
      <child Name="ch2" ID="0x22" info="the second child" numb="7"/>
   </Node>
</root>
```

by applying the following stylesheet to your input:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/parent">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Node | child">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(*)]"/>       
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>       
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To sort the `child` elements by their `Name`, change:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child">  
    <xsl:sort select="Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Comment: You are right.It's working, but how can I sort ascending after name's of child. I have a lot of child in my file. Thanks

Comment: @John124 I have added a suggestion to my answer, but I am not sure I understand what you're asking.